# Azure APIM JWT token validation fails with unclear error

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-api-management

I configured a policy in Azure Api Management which includes a jwt token check.
The policy is as is follows:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401"
                   require-expiration-time="false" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
            <issuer-signing-keys>
                <key>MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAu1SU1LfVLPHCozMxH2Mo4lgOEePzNm0tRgeLezV6ffAt0gunVTLw7onLRnrq0/IzW7yWR7QkrmBL7jTKEn5u+qKhbwKfBstIs+bMY2Zkp18gnTxKLxoS2tFczGkPLPgizskuemMghRniWaoLcyehkd3qqGElvW/VDL5AaWTg0nLVkjRo9z+40RQzuVaE8AkAFmxZzow3x+VJYKdjykkJ0iT9wCS0DRTXu269V264Vf/3jvredZiKRkgwlL9xNAwxXFg0x/XFw005UWVRIkdgcKWTjpBP2dPwVZ4WWC+9aGVd+Gyn1o0CLelf4rEjGoXbAAEgAqeGUxrcIlbjXfbcmwIDAQAB</key>
            </issuer-signing-keys>
        </validate-jwt>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

The test request I send contains the Authorization Header with value
`Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0.NHVaYe26MbtOYhSKkoKYdFVomg4i8ZJd8_-RU8VNbftc4TSMb4bXP3l3YlNWACwyXPGffz5aXHc6lty1Y2t4SWRqGteragsVdZufDn5BlnJl9pdR_kdVFUsra2rWKEofkZeIC4yWytE58sMIihvo9H1ScmmVwBcQP6XETqYd0aSHp1gOa9RdUPDvoXQ5oqygTqVtxaDr6wUFKrKItgBMzWIdNZ6y7O9E0DhEPTbE9rfBo6KTFsHAZnMg4k68CDp2woYIaXbmYTWcvbzIuHO7_37GT79XdIwkm95QJ7hYC9RiwrV7mesbY4PAahERJawntho0my942XheVLmGwLMBkQ`

When I enter this key with -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- and -----END PUBLIC KEY----- and the token in **jwt.io** it says Signature Verified.

However, in API Management when I send a test request with trace enabled I get the following error which I do not understand:

```json
validate-jwt (-1.088 ms)
{
 "message": "JWT Validation Failed: IDX10503: Signature validation failed.
 Token does not have a kid. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey,
 KeyId: '', InternalId: 'D3UHVKlh_cCYIRkkI3Amxvzr2mtlzxMVD-ZG6JwNQqs'. ,
 KeyId: \r\n'. Number of keys in TokenValidationParameters: '1'. \n
 Number of keys in Configuration: '0'. \nExceptions caught:
 \n 'System.NotSupportedException: IDX10634: Unable to create the 
 SignatureProvider.\nAlgorithm: 'RS256', SecurityKey: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey,
 KeyId: '', InternalId: 'D3UHVKlh_cCYIRkkI3Amxvzr2mtlzxMVD-ZG6JwNQqs'.'\n is not supported. 
 The list of supported algorithms is available here: 
 https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/supported-algorithms\r\n   
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateSignatureProvider
 (SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures, Boolean cacheProvider)\r\n
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateForVerifying
 (SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean cacheProvider)\r\n   
 at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature
 (Byte[] encodedBytes, Byte[] signature, SecurityKey key, String algorithm,
 SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)\r\n
 at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature
 (String token, JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, 
 BaseConfiguration configuration)\r\n'.\ntoken: 'hidden'.."
}
```

I am very confused by the *System.NotSupportedException* part. RS256 is clearly supported according to MS-Docs. I am also confused why it mentions a Symmetric security key.

Can someone tell me what this error is exactly saying and what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You are using rs256,

the key may be provided either via an OpenID configuration endpoint, or by providing the ID of an uploaded certificate (in PFX format) that contains the public key, or the modulus-exponent pair of the public key.

See this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validate-jwt-policy#token-validation-with-rsa-certificate and this 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validate-jwt-policy#usage-notes

Comment: How are you generating the token and key? If you are using jwt.io to generate the token, then within <key>pass the secret key</key> or refer https://feranto.github.io/azure-apim-lab/apimanagement-7.html

Comment: @MohamadHaidar Damn, you are right. Providing just the Public Key alone apparently is not working! I wish I read that earlier.

Comment: That is correct, I am adding my comment as an answer so others can benefit of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token is signed using rs256, the key may be provided either via an OpenID configuration endpoint, or by providing the ID of an uploaded certificate (in PFX format) that contains the public key, or the modulus-exponent pair of the public key. See this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validate-jwt-policy#token-validation-with-rsa-certificate and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validate-jwt-policy#usage-notes

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you use first of all is not correct.

After you uploaded a Certificate (Go To Certificates on the left menu, then go to the voice "Certificates" - not CA Certificates - and add your certificate with your name - i.e., id that you will use below)

```
    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized" require-expiration-time="true" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
        <issuer-signing-keys>
            <key certificate-id="{the certificate id that you uploaded}" />
        </issuer-signing-keys>
    </validate-jwt>
```

This is the syntax

The certificate can only be a .PFX certificate

Assuming you have a Private Key, you can generate the certificate as follows.
First of all, from your private.pem file, which looks something like this

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
M*************************z9
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

(Note that it is not a certificate, because it should contain other data).

run the followings:

1. openssl req -key private.pem -new -x509 -days 365 -out certificate.pem
   which will create a certificate "certificate.pem" with expiry date in 365 days. You will be prompted to insert other data, such as organization name, etc.. you can also leave it blank.
2. openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey private.pem -in certificate.pem

This will finally give you the certificate.PFX file. You will be prompted a Export Password. You use one by your choice and memorize it for later when you upload the certificate online. You will be asked to use this password.